# Use Network SocketFactory with SSL

Tags: android, sockets, ssl, networking, okhttp

I'm trying to reach my server from WiFi or Mobile Data, depending on which interface is answering. The use case is the following :
- WiFi is always on.
- If the server is not responding through the WiFi (because there is no internet connection for example), then I redirect future requests to the cellular data.
- When the connection is back through the WiFi, I redirect next requests to the WiFi.

To achieve this, I wanted to use the ConnectivityManager with TRANSPORT_CELLULAR or TRANSPORT_WIFI. Then it returns a Network object which I can use.

After that I planned to pass the socketFactory from the Network class to the OkHttpClient.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .socketFactory(network.getSocketFactory())
        .build();
```

Problem : the server uses a https connection. So I'm building the OkHttpClient using socketSSLFactory, which is build with SSLContext and its method getSocketFactory.

So the question is the following : how can I bind the OkHttpClient to a Network AND to a SSL Socket Factory ?

Comment: Using `OkHttpClient.Builder.sslSocketFactory()` is the correct solution for creating HTTPS connections with OkHttp. However, since `Network` doesn't provide an `SSLSocketFactory`, you will probably have to resort to implementing your own class that extends `SSLSocketFactory` and pass an instance of that class to `Builder.sslSocketFactory()`. Override `createSocket()` in your class to return a `Socket` from `SSLContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket()`, passing it a `Socket` from `network.getSocketFactory().createSocket()`. Not sure if that would work, but might be worth a try.

Comment: The `getSocketFactory` from `SSLContext` is returning a `SSLSocketFactory`, and the `getSocketFactory` from `Network` is return a `SocketFactory`. So it seems I am stuck because of that. Right now I will use the `bindProcessToNetwork` method and recreate my okhttp client but I am not super fan of this solution

Comment: Read my previous comment again more carefully, and read the documentation. `SSLSocketFactory.createSocket()` takes a `Socket` as input and returns a new `Socket`. The input `Socket` is the underlying connection that SSL runs on top of. The returned `Socket` handles encrypted I/O using that connection. It is fine that the two `Socket`s are from different factories. My suggestion would allow you to get that initial `Socket` from the `Network` and then bind the SSL `Socket` to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I finally find out how to perform that.
It requires to use both socketFactory and SSLSocketFactory of OkHttp builder.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .sslSocketFactory(new MySSLSocketFactory(), new MyTrustManager())
    .socketFactory(network.getSocketFactory())
    .dns(new NetworkDns())
    .hostnameVerifier(new MyHostnameVerifier());
```

Concretely, `MySSLSocketFactory` is not binded to my network object. I don't need to override the `createSocket` method in it. I just pass the socket factory of my `network` object to the OkHttp builder.

Don't forget to override the `dns` as well to perform the name resolution on the `network` you want. (cf [Perform network-specific host name resolutions using Network.getAllByName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48193088/perform-network-specific-host-name-resolutions-using-network-getallbyname))

Comment: So, as I understood, BOTH socketFactory and sslSocketFactory has to be set, and SSLSocketFactory can just be a default one. Is HostNameVerifier needed for it to work?